# Remove remote branches in Git

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

I want to delete some remote branches of my project repository. I've run the next command:

```
git push origin :name_of_branch
```

and when I list the remote branches with

```
git branch -r
```

the branch that I've deleted doesn't appear, but a partner of mine run

```
git fetch
```

and later

```
git branch -r
```

and in the list, the branch `name_of_branch` that I had deleted, is still in the list. However, when he tries to delete the branch with

```
git push origin :name_of_branch
```

He receives the next message:

```
error: unable to delete 'name_of_branch': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'the_name_of_the_repository'
```

How could I delete the branch completely of the list?

Comment: Duplicate of [Delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2003505/456814).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This happens because when this partner of yours runs `git fetch`, the branch deletion is not "applied" to his repository. `fetch` only updates and adds branches.

They can run `git remote prune origin` to trim away remote branches in their list that no longer exist in the upstream repository.

Comment: FYI, `git remote prune` is somewhat deprecated in favor of `git fetch --prune` or `git fetch -p`. See the [Git version 1.6.6 release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.0.0/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.6.txt#L162-L166): "[`git fetch --prune` makes] `git remote update` and `git remote prune` less necessary (there is no plan to remove `remote
update` nor `remote prune`, though)."

Answer (score 11):

`git fetch --prune <remote>` can be used to remove all your remote-tracking branches that are tracking branches that no longer exist in a remote repository (i.e. they were deleted in the remote). From the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for `fetch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

> `-p`
>
> `--prune`
>
> After fetching, remove any remote-tracking branches which no longer exist on the remote.

You can also remote obsolete remote-tracking branches with the command

```
git branch -D -r <remote>/<branch>
```

as stated in [the documentation for `git branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> Use `-r` together with `-d` to delete remote-tracking branches. Note, that it only makes sense to delete remote-tracking branches if they no longer exist in the remote repository or if `git fetch` was configured not to fetch them again.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch -r -d 'remote-branch'
```